# T-Sql Script for SQL Server Backup Maintenance Plan?

Tags: sql-server, backup

What is T-Sql script for backup maintenance plan? I want to manage that from app.

actually, i want to Configure Automatic Backups with Task Scheduler with T-Sql script from app .

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok

you should to use sql agent

In Object Explorer, Connect to SQL Server, Expand 'SQL Server Agent' node, Expand Jobs;  right click ; select menu 'New Job'

Type in name of the SQL Agent Job

Create a backup job Step

Click on 'New' to create a new job step

Type in name for job step and T-SQL statement to backup database

and in last step you can click OK to save or click on "Script" to generate script and use it in your program.

Comment: TNX Farrokh. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow these steps:

1- Create the job:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
   @job_name = N'BackupDBTestJob', 
   @enabled = 1, 
   @description = N'Create a complete backup of database TestDB' ; 
GO
```

2- Add a new step to this job:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'BackupDBTestJob', 
    @step_name = N'Create the backup', 
    @subsystem = N'TSQL', 
    @command = N'BACKUP DATABASE DBTest TO DISK = ''c:\DBTest.bak'''
GO
```

3- You can schedule the job:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'RunOnceAt23', 
    @freq_type = 4, -- means run daily 
    @freq_interval = 1, -- means run once every 1 day
    @active_start_time = 233000 ; -- means at 23:00:00
GO
```

4- And attach this newly created schedule to the job

```
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'BackupDBTestJob'
   @schedule_name = N'RunOnceAt23; 
GO
```

And there is [this sample in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953.aspx#TsqlProcedure) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

To back up an entire database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE { database_name | @database_name_var } 
  TO <backup_device> [ ,...n ] 
  [ <MIRROR TO clause> ] [ next-mirror-to ]
  [ WITH { DIFFERENTIAL | <general_WITH_options> [ ,...n ] } ]
[;]
```